# In HAML, how to write comments in :javascript region so that comments do not show to the public?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, comments, haml

in HAML, we can write comments using

```
-# some comment and it won't become HTML and made public
```

but if it is inside

```
:javascript
  -# comments like this line will break the javascript interpreter as it becomes javascript code
  // so we are forced to use comment like this and is publicly viewable
```

is there a way to make it non-public?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#{}`- blocks are evaluated, so you can write

```
#{ # this is a ruby comment, but still a comment (newline is required)
}
```

Comment: Works great. A bit ugly, but that's ok.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: filters in Haml aren't processed by Haml at all, they're simply sent off to the relevant filter processor. For `:javascript`, this is a simple processor that just wraps up the text in script tags. There's no support for anything fancy like removing comments. If you want something like that, I'd suggest adding a custom filter that uses some sort of Javascript minifier.

Comment: seems like the things inside :javascript filter, the #{i} will be evaluated... maybe that's the only thing?  <%= i %> won't work either.